# Let f:$A \to B$ and $g:B \to A$. Prove that...

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B \to A$. Prove that $f$ is one-to-one and onto if $f∘g$ is one-to-one and $g∘f$ is onto.

I realize the logic behind it, I realize $g∘f:B \to B$ being surjective (onto) implies that everything in $B$ is being hit. Now $f∘g:A \to A$ being injective means that there exists only one path from $A$ to $A$. I am just not sure how to combine the information to show that $f$ is bijective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \circ g$ is injective, $g$ has to be injective. Indeed, let $g(a) = g(b)$. Then $(f \circ g)(a) = (f \circ g)(b)$ and by the injectivity of $f \circ g$, $a = b$. Similarly, surjectivity of $g \circ f$ implies surjectivity of $g$. Hence $g$ is bijective. Now apply $g^{-1}$ to see that $f$ is also bijective.

Comment: What do you mean by "apply g inverse"?

Comment: Consider $f = f \circ g \circ g^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ g \circ f$.

Comment: I haven't seen that before. I knew how to prove it for g, but that last step was what I was missing. Thanks.